# Configuring Cisco ISR router as dial-up server

Tags: cisco, wan

I am working on replacing Cisco AS5350 with Cisco ISR 2900 series , on the old setup I have only one profile to apply for the incoming calls and one IP Pool, but with the new setup I have new requirements to recognize between two types of users and assign them different IP's from different pools and apply different ACL (Two template interfaces) .
I am wondering if it is possible to recognize the incoming calls based on the dialed number and assign them the connection template based on that? then I will use  different calling number for each group of users. if any one have configuration example for that please share